# How to send File and String data using HttpURLConnection in android

Tags: android, file-upload, httpurlconnection, android-networking

I am using HttpURLConnection to upload a file to the server but i could not figure out how can i add other parameters to send String data along with file.

This is the code i am using to upload the file.

```
public String sendFileToServer(String filename, String targetUrl) {
    String response = "error";
    Log.e("Image filename", filename);
    Log.e("url", targetUrl);
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    // DataInputStream inputStream = null;

    String pathToOurFile = filename;
    String urlServer = targetUrl;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH:mm:ss");

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024;
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                pathToOurFile));

        URL url = new URL(urlServer);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Allow Inputs & Outputs
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
        // Enable POST method
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

        String connstr = null;
        connstr = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
                + pathToOurFile + "\"" + lineEnd;
        Log.i("Connstr", connstr);

        outputStream.writeBytes(connstr);
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // Read file
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        Log.e("Image length", bytesAvailable + "");
        try {
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                try {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    response = "outofmemoryerror";
                    return response;
                }
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "error";
            return response;
        }
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                + lineEnd);


        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
        Log.i("Server Response Code ", "" + serverResponseCode);
        Log.i("Server Response Message", serverResponseMessage);

        if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
            response = "true";
        }

        String CDate = null;
        Date serverTime = new Date(connection.getDate());
        try {
            CDate = df.format(serverTime);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Date Exception", e.getMessage() + " Parse Exception");
        }
        Log.i("Server Response Time", CDate + "");

        filename = CDate
                + filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf("."),
                filename.length());
        Log.i("File Name in Server : ", filename);

        fileInputStream.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        outputStream = null;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Exception handling
        response = "error";
        Log.e("Send file Exception", ex.getMessage() + "");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

I have used Volley previously but it fails to upload when file is large, I have to upload Video files up to 20 MB, so if you have any better solution please let me know.

I am using this code in `Service` so even if user close the app the uploading should continue.

Comment: Do not use HttpURLConnection

Comment: Don't do that by yourself. There are couple of libraries that do they work better, are tested and maintain by qualified people. Like this http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Comment: @AntonA. Hi, Is there any specific reason for not using it, i would like to know, thanks?

Comment: Like @DennyDog say, because there are a lot of libs for this. Most common is http://square.github.io/retrofit/. I always use only it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work:

```
outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

// To send string data
outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + stringName + "\""+lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes(stringValue + lineEnd);
outputStream.flush();

// To send file data
outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile + "\"" + lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
```

For more details: [link](https://blog.morizyun.com/blog/android-httpurlconnection-post-multipart/index.html)